# scrollview with tablelayout and linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a `ScrollView` layout with a `TableLayout` in which i have a `TableRow` which consists of three `TextViews`.

The problem arises when i try to align the `TextViews` with the screen. The `TextViews` don't take up the space of the screen and kind of cram up.

I have attached the code too if you guys need to review it ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_reciept"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.spuck.LayoutTable">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:src="@drawable/the_one_3"
            android:id="@+id/the_one"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addButton">


            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/maintable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_two_table_layout">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Date"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Session Time"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Average Speed"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:text="Scan item barcode"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in LinearLayout `android:layout_weight="2.5"` which is sum of layout weight of LinearLayout children. After this Layout should be aligned to left and right.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_two_table_layout">
```

Comment: I will try this for sure, now I have tun into another prob, I added a navigation menu and a bottom navigation bar in this same layout in the end and now its doesn't show me the table. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry without source code, it's pretty hard to tell where the problem is. I've tried to implement bottom navigation bar based on this tutorial https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0#.4bvk8trr4 for me its working alright heres the result: https://postimg.org/image/n1gjcalm7/ Didn't add a navigation menu, but it should not break the table. If you would have still problems with it I think you should post a new question.

Comment: lets chat about it, I am new to StackOverflow so please message me first if you can

Comment: I don't write much on stackoverflow either and to create chatroom it is needed reputation of 100. So at this moment I am missing 4 rep to start chat.

Comment: alright, is there any other way we can talk about this if possible ....

Comment: There are many comunicators in the internet. I found mirc http://www.mirc.com/get.html chanel: android_layout password:12345 is it alright?